# Curl POST array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, curl

I'm trying to reproduce a `cURL` to `POST` an array of hashes and having trouble with the syntax. This is the basic format I want:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops -d \
  "shop[users][]=1 \
   &shop[users][]=2\
   &shop[users][]=c"
```

How do I turn the values `1`, `2`, and `c` into hashes?

On my Rails API, I want the object to look like this:

```
{
  shop: {
    users: [
      {
        name: "Foo",
        age: 34
      },
      {
        name: "Bar",
        age: 12
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Update**

I tried the `here-doc` solution below but Rails parses that wrong, giving me:

```
{"{  shop: {    users: "=>{"      {        name: \"Foo\",        age: 34      },      {        name: \"Bar\",        age: 12      }    "=>{"  }}"=>nil}},"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"shops"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and didn't wanted to use a json file, so i find out that this way also works fine! (at least with Rails 3)

```
curl -i http://localhost:3000/team/999/transfers \
 -X "POST" \
 -d "team[transfers][][player_in_id]=1" \
 -d "team[transfers][][player_out_id]=2" \
 -d "team[transfers][][player_in_id]=3" \
 -d "team[transfers][][player_out_id]=4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this using a *here-doc* :

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops -d "@-" <<EOF
{
  shop: {
    users: [
      {
        name: "Foo",
        age: 34
      },
      {
        name: "Bar",
        age: 12
      }
    ]
  }
}
EOF
```

Comment: thanks. Tagging this question with Rails also because Rails does some funky params parsing. Your solution didn't get parsed correctly.